# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 ERROR

Tags: php

I get this error, but the code works correctly.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
```

Here is the php:

```
$surl = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
$params = explode('/test.php?=', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
foreach ($params AS $key => $value) {$$key = $value;}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/test.php?='){
    $link=$params[1];
}else{
    $link=$params[1];
}
```

Comment: What is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value?

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do, but it doesn't look right. Perhaps post a question explaining the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've posted the whole stack trace, but it seems your $params array doesn't have 2 indices in it, which leads me to believe $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] does not include '/test.php?='. Print the request uri to see what it does contain, and explode using that as the delimiter.